# How to ensure an LED is completely off when pin is set LOW?

Tags: arduino, led

I have a situation where, when the associated pin is set LOW, the LED still glows faintly.  As this is to be used in a darkened area, it is quite noticeable.

So far, I have encountered this only with one of my Arduino boards, and only when the LED colour in use is pink, as opposed to yellow or blue, which are the only other colours I have tried.  Increasing the resistor from pin to LED to 1K ohm does not resolve the issue. Also, the use of a different pink LED does not affect the outcome.

I realize that setting a pin "LOW" does not imply zero current, so how should I handle this problem?  Though I am quite familiar with the Arduino, my knowledge of Electronics in general is quite shallow, and ask that any response take this into consideration.

Comment: Schematics, please.

Comment: ...you have a pink LED‽

Comment: It should be off on LOW. Are you sure that the Arduino pin is not in INPUT mode with internal weak pullup?

Comment: Did you measure voltages?

Comment: Pink LEDs will glow from *any* UV source. Make sure that there are no nearby UV sources that could illuminate the phosphorescent material.

Comment: @uint128_t: [NTE30126](http://www.microcenter.com/product/390148/5mm_ultra_bright_pink_leds_5-pack)

Comment: @uint128_t Last time I was shopping for LEDs I noticed that pink is not  a super-uncommon available color. Can't remember the chemistry involved.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Wow.. Microcenter sure don't like us foreigners! http://i.imgur.com/huLrCYO.png

Comment: @pipe: O_O Well that's nasty. It was just for the picture of the LED itself. Imagine a water clear 5mm LED but bright pink and that's what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The LED should extinguish completely.  You must have a wiring error or are not driving it correctly in the software.

One possibility is that you have the pull-up enabled in the processor.

The AVR microprocessor has the ability to enable a high-value pull-up resistor (20k) if needed.  If you do this when you intend to turn the LED off it will glow dimly.

One way this can happen is to set the pin_mode() as INPUT_PULLUP.  It will also happen if you turn the pin to an input and write a 1 to the pin output register.

The usual way to connect an LED to an Arduino or other processor is to connect one end of the LED to the +5V with the other end connected to the output pin through a resistor in the range of 220-1000 ohm depending upon the LED and brightness required.

Some people call this resistor a current-limiting resistor, I prefer to call it a current defining resistor.  It is not there to protect the LED it is to set the desired current.

You write 0 to the pin to turn the LED on and a 1 to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Pink LEDs work by using a phosphor to convert the light emitted by an ultraviolet LED to a mixture of visible wavelengths. That phosphor can be excited by ultraviolet light from other sources. I suspect this might be what's happening here.

Comment: Yep, like the blue LED.  All my white LEDs glow whenever only the blue is on.   BTW it's not a UV LED but a Royal Blue or Deep Blue around 450 nm, a near UVA LED.

Answer (score 0):

In good old days when microcontroller was not able to provide enough current to drive LED or even BJT and that situation what we usually did was to use invert logic topology.

For example when Arduino Pin=1 LED will be OFF and vice versa.

Connect Cathod of LED to Arduino Pin and Anode of LED connect to Power supply via current limiting resistor and try logic 1 on arduino it must turn off the LED. Use logic 0 to turn ON.

Answer (score 0):

This really isnt possible.  The led has a resistor with it as the voltage level is generally wrong for an led, so you either have high and high on either side of the led or low and low on either side to make it "off" lets say low, low, one of those is the system ground the other is a ground connected inside the part (more transistors and resistors). so techincally they are not exactly at the same level, and can never be, close but never exactly.  Even if you were to use a relay you wouldnt be exactly zero as there are different length traces (electrically) to a common ground point.

now if this is charlieplexed then you could reverse the polarity if high low is on then low high should definitely be off, but I am sure someone will correct me on this.

If you are seeing a glow, then you probably dont have one side pulled high or low right so that you have a high high or low low situation to the same potential there is some resistance that is creating a voltage divider making your led a little bit high low just enough to glow.  Or maybe you are blinking it and dont realize it...

Comment: check your pull up resistor maybe you have the wrong value...

Answer (score 0):

Since I know the 8051 well, I'll talk about it since I ran into a similar problem at the beginning.

The port pins (at least the ones I'm using for the answer) are designed to allow input and output under certain conditions:

If that pin is set to logic high in code, then the pin itself will be set to high-impedance. If you try to hook up the LED and resistor in series from pin to ground, then you'll get anything from a dim light to no light. If you set the pin to logic low in code, then the LED does not light at all in the same configuration.

The easiest approach would be to wire up the LED inverted style. In my circuit, its LED and resistor (LED2 and R3) in series connected between VCC (which is 5V regulated) and a port pin. By doing this, the LED would either light normally (if pin is set to low in code) or it would be off (if pin is set to high in code).

The reason the easiest approach works is because the micro has internal pull-up resistors. If pin is set to logic high, then the LED and resistor would be connected from VCC back to VCC through microcontroller's internal pull-up resistor thereby giving LED zero voltage (meaning LED is off). If pin is set to logic low, then LED would light because then you have a normal LED circuit which is VCC to LED with resistor connected to ground.

**an answer to your way**

Well it might not be the best answer, but since the micro can provide very little output (via internal pull-up) and zero output, you could run the output through an op-amp and adjust the potentiometer to create a reference voltage and if the voltage of the micro controller pin is bigger than the reference voltage then the LED lights. otherwise it doesn't. You may need to play with the resistor values a bit to get the desired effect.

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not set the correct pin direction (I saw it before if the pin was set as input not output). Another potential reason is that you fried your pin and it always has some potential on it (I have such atmega in my drawer)